# TestFlight build on App Store Connect stuck at 'Ready to Submit'

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

Since the recent update to App Store Connect, I can't figure out at all as to how I submit a new TestFlight build for beta review.

Under 'iTunes Connect Users' it says 'Ready to Test', while under 'External Testers' it says 'Ready to Submit'.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but how do I submit for beta review? I already have multiple versions on TestFlight.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Discovered the answer, the key was to go on iTunes Connect > My Apps > TestFlight > Any Group > Builds, and then submitted it via adding a new build in there.

Comment: To add on to this, if the build is listed there on the group but still says "Ready to Submit" - remove it (the minus on the far right) and re-add the build - something didn't go right the first time and the prompts on the screen ended before they got you to submit.

Comment: FWIW that might not work as of today TestFlight has a bug in it. I have opened a case. Waiting for them to fix it.

Comment: Could you post the case # so I can reference it in my own case?

Comment: What @BarrettJ said fixed the issue for me. I deployed using fastlane and there were no errors/warnings but removing and readding the build fixed the issue for me

Comment: There is another answer now for App Store Connect - see below.

Answer (score 16):

In App Store Connect, this process has slightly changed. You must **create a testing group** in order to start external testing.

Here's how to do that:

1. Navigate to My Apps/TestFlight and click on **Add External Testers** on the left sidebar.

   [image: Add External Testers button on the left sidebar]
2. Give your group a name and click on **Create**.

   [image: Create a New Group alert]
3. Select **Builds** on the top and click on the little plus icon underneath.

   [image: The Builds tab]
4. Select your build and give the test information necessary for the review process.

   [image: Select a Build to Test alert]

Answer (score 4):

In order to Submit an app for review you'll need to add external users from the TestFlight > Builds screen. Select the build you want to submit, and add Individual Testers from this screen. As long as at least one of them is external a series of dialog boxes will walk you through the rest of the submission.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was similar, stuck on the `ready to submit` step. I had a successful build in the appsote, I just need to update its version to newer one. [This article](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev480217e79) actually helps me.

> Create a new version
>
> When you’re ready to distribute a new version of your app, you create a version using the same app record you created for the original version. The new version will be available free to customers who purchased a previous version. You can only create a new version if the current version status is Ready for Sale or Developer Removed from Sale.
>
> Keep in mind that it's not possible to revert to a previous version on the App Store if you have an issue with your app. You must create and submit a new version.

**Role is very important, with developer role you can't submit the app for review.**

> Required role: Account Holder, Admin, or App Manager. See Role permissions.

After having the proper role you need to follow these steps

1. From the homepage, click My Apps, then select the app.
2. The App Store page opens with App Information selected.
3. In the left column, click the Version or Platform Add button (+) and choose a platform from the pop-up menu.
4. In the New Version dialog, enter an incremental App Store version number, and click Create.
5. Under App Information, review and enter metadata about the new version.

   When you create a new version, the metadata from the current version is transferred to the new version automatically. Properties you can change will appear in editable fields on the App Information page.

   For a description of the version properties, go to Platform version information. For the required and localizable properties, refer to Required, localizable, and editable properties.
6. In the upper-right corner, click Save.

   7.In Xcode, increment the build string before you upload your build to App Store Connect, as described in Set the version number and build string.
7. Upload your new build to App Store Connect.
8. When you are ready to submit your build, add it to your latest App Store version, then submit your app to app review.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was similar, stuck on the ready to submit step. I had a successful build in the appsote, I just need to update its version to newer one. I added a detailed answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57160753/557396

Answer (score 0):

Go to my apps. Then select the + icon next to the iOS App. And then create a new version. Then select the build in the test flight. Finally, save the details and submit your app for review.